# 7zip: can't compress directories from text file, "WARNING: No more files"

Tags: linux, bash, 7zip

I've diff'ed a directory on a home and work computer and got a list of directories I have at home but not at work:

```
comm -23 <(ls home_dir) <(ssh login@address ls work_dir) >missing
```

Then I edited the file `missing` so that it has become like this:

```
"dir1" "dir2" "dir3" .....
```

Then I tried to compress missing directories with `7zip`:

```
7z a missing.7z $(cat missing)
```

But I got an error message:

```
Scanning the drive:

WARNING: No more files
"dir1"


WARNING: No more files
"dir2"


WARNING: No more files
"dir3"

.............
```

When I pasted the directory list to a `7zip` command:

```
7z a missing.7z "dir1" "dir2" "dir3" ......
```

everything was fine.

Why can't I get a directory list from file?

Comment: Command substitution (and other expansion) results only go through string-splitting and glob expansion, not other parsing stages (like quote removal).

Comment: ...I assume that when you were editing, you *added* quotes? Just take that step out.

Comment: [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) is relevant to understanding root cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the quotes from the file, your command will work. I don't know exactly why this happens, but I think it has something to do with how arguments are passed. I think `"dir1"` is literally sent, and that's what 7z complains about.

If you have spaces in the filenames or in directories, I suggest to use the following code. You will have to change the "missing" file to have directories or files separated with newlines.

```
#! /bin/bash
archive=test.7z
while read -r line; do 7z a ${archive} "$line"; done < "missing"
```

```
dir1
dir2
dir 4
```

I couldn't get anything else to work with `7z`.

Comment: Unfortunately, escaping didn't help, but the directories without spaces are compressed fine.